# Retrieving data from custom useraccounts fields

Tags: meteor

I'm using the Atmosphere package `meteor-useraccounts`, but I cannot figure out how to retrieve data from custom made fields.

I made the field:

```
AccountsTemplates.addField({
    _id: 'callsign',
    type: 'text',
    placeholder: {
        signUp: "Callsign"
    },
    required: true,
});
```

and I would like to get the logged in user's callsign from the user's collection.

I tried to see if the registration pushes the data to the user's collection, but it seems not so.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: when you say you "tried to see if the registration pushes the data to the user's collection", what did you check?

Comment: @zim When I registered, I console logged the user's collection but I did not see the callsign data there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try hooking into the account creation, it should show you your values in options.profile. then you can save them to the user object or wherever you would like. put this code somewhere on the server:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
    console.log('--------------------------------');
    console.log('options:', options);
    console.log('--------------------------------');
    console.log('user:', user);
    console.log('--------------------------------');

    return user;
});
```

be sure to return the user object at the end.